# Error when cargo build node-template substrate

Tags: substrate, polkadot

When I run cargo build --release, it happened like that

> kali in ~/project/substrate-node-template on branch tags/v3.0.0 >
> cargo build --release -p node-template
> error: failed to create directory
> `/home/kali/project/substrate-node-template/target/release/.fingerprint/node-template-6dc979de512b7742`
>
> Caused by:   No space left on device (os error 28)

Thank everyone!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would carefully reading the error, as it clearly prompts
`No space left on device`